# Who implemented BitcoinPayment at the Bitcoin wiki?

Tags: bitcoin-wiki

Who was the technical person who implement/integrated [BitcoinPayment](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BitcoinPayment) at the Bitcoin wiki? How can he be contacted?

Comment: I think BitcoinPayment should be enhanced to stop new user from registering, not just editing. The Recent Changes page is totally spammed by new users - https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Special:RecentChanges

Comment: FYI, here is how to view the recent changes without user pages, which filters out this spam: https://en.bitcoin.it/w/index.php?namespace=2&invert=1&title=Special%3ARecentChanges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As Nanotube said](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=94903.msg1985705#msg1985705), MagicalTux made this plugin himself.

Answer (score 2):

The [history of the page](https://en.bitcoin.it/w/index.php?title=BitcoinPayment&action=history) suggests that [Nanotube](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/User%3aNanotube), [MagicalTux](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/User%3aMagicalTux) and [Rdymac](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/User%3aRdymac) were the last that edited the page.

The first two of them have contact instructions on their Wiki profile, only the latter does not.

Comment: Hello! I added instructions for Spanish users because if people pay the fee under 'en.' subdomain they won't be able to edit the 'es.' subdomain site. **edit:** I added my profile to the wiki https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/User:Rdymac